# Simple connectedness after deleting a curve

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

This question is in the context of branch cuts for $\log z$. I was thinking of the possibility of cuts apart from the usual rays.

Suppose $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ is any simple continuous curve joining $0$ to $\infty$ which is homotopic to the ray $\{z\leq 0\}$ beginning at 0. Intuitively it appears that $\mathbb{C} \setminus \gamma$ will be simply connected. If so, how does one prove it?

Comment: Since the curve is homotopic (maybe we want isotopic?) to the negative ray $\gamma$, we might as well work with that. If $\mathbb C \setminus \{z\leq 0\}$ is simply connected, then the contraction of any loop can be deformed via that homotopy to contract any loop in $\mathbb C\setminus \gamma$.

Comment: @Keshav Of course! Compose the homotopies. Thanks. Is it really necessary to require isotopy?

Comment: I guess I am actually thinking the curve should remain simple the entire time, so maybe a "simple homotopy"? An isotopy would definitely preserve this.

Comment: I may have been hasty in claiming to understand your first response. How can a loop in {plane \ γ} be shrunk to a point by leveraging the homotopy between γ and {z≤0}? Also, I guess my question really should have been: will deleting any simple curve joining 0 & ∞ leave the Riemann sphere simply connected?

Comment: I don't know if I can describe exact maps, but in terms of homotopy type, the plane $\mathbb C$ is the same as a sphere minus a point is the same as a sphere minus a disk is the same as a sphere minus a "thickened" $\gamma$ (a nbd around $\gamma$), right?